# Why indexOf returns -1 although objects are same in java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have a list.

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
list = new ArrayList<Object>(map.values());

for(Object o : list){            
   if (o.toString().contains(textClob)){
       int objectIndex = list.indexOf(o);
}
```

[image]

Why indexOf returns -1 although objects are same?

[image]

Comment: because memory is different for each object

Comment: Maybe the CLOB object has `equals()` implemented to return `false`, because the data isn't available, so it cannot compare to check if they have the same content. The point of CLOBs is to not load the entire content into memory, but if you're ok with loading content, so you can compare it, use `String` instead of `Clob`.

Comment: @NegiRox , how can I set them same?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your initializing the list twice. Try this instead:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(map.values());

for(Object o : list){

               if (o.toString().contains(textClob)){
                   int objectIndex = list.indexOf(o);
}
```

Comment: No worries, sorry it didn't work.
Usually when a list returns -1 it means it doesn't have any data in the list.
Maybe check your lists are being populated with data.
You can check how many objects are in a list with:
list.size() and map.size()